# facebook postcard and payload

Tags: facebook-oauth

I am having a native application in facebook. I tried to post to a user wall using the following header format

https://graph.facebook.com/100002944254185/feed?message=today

Authorization: OAuth oauth_version=1.0,oauth_nonce=5887e5b11904194f7d217e9b7f795d62, oauth_timestamp=1317623602,
oauth_consumer_key=129042607197622,
oauth_token=AAAB1XRLDTbYBAIfcTKw3mowkwjld89A4K7JVQHZAOM60Tmb8za6wjNq8sPTuHhiAVojKyXm9r1SB3OWlSkKWI2sn9lSAwQGE0giA0UTgCfgXcd0ZCe, oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1,
oauth_signature=GKl%2Bvf3Vaq25XY7dTnb%2FJg3fip8%3D
Content-Type: application/X-WWW-form-urlencoded

when executing getting an error as

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "Expected 1 '.' in the input between the postcard and the payload"

Can anyone say what does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of https://graph.facebook.com/100002944254185/feed?message=today and then the messy Authorization tags below it, just append the access_token onto the querystring of the https call so it looks like https://graph.facebook.com/100002944254185/feed?message=today&access_token=xxxx  and HTTP Post that.